# How can I make emacs compile my c++ code and run it in a new window?

Tags: c++, emacs, compilation

Is there a way I can make emacs compile and run my code in an external console window with the command `M-x compile` (what I mean by external console window is that I want it to run my code in a new console window like it does when I run my C++ code in visual studio).

I want emacs to automatically open up a new console window and run the executable after `M-x compile` like this:

[image]

Comment: Emacs is not an IDE like Visual Studio, it's an editor at its core.  You may be able to load packages, like CEDET, that will allow Emacs to call a compiler and maybe act like a debugger (I haven't tested the debugging capabilities yet).  There should be existing commands that allow you to run executables.

Comment: At the end of the day `M-x compile` just tells `emacs` to run a command that has been previously specified (e.g. in your `.emacs` config file).  The command can be anything you like.

Comment: eg. to compile and run `C-u M-x compile` 'gcc -o a.out my-c-file.c && ./a.out'.  Successive calls to `compile` will default to previous entered command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally with Emacs, when you want some obscure (i.e. some simple, or special to your use case) automation, you just write a command, which does what you want.

Here is such an example. Following Elisp code calls a function `and-run`, when compilation is finished (through using hook `compilation-finish-functions`).

```
(defun and-run (&rest _)
  "run after comilation, an not elaborated example function"
  (interactive)
  (let ((exe "./test.out")
        (prevent-closing (concat "echo \"Press Enter to continue\"" ";"
                                 "read"))
        (terminal "xterm -e"))
  (when (file-exists-p exe)
    (let ((my-command (concat exe ";" prevent-closing)))
      (shell-command (format "%s %s" terminal (shell-quote-argument my-command)))))))

(add-hook 'compilation-finish-functions #'and-run)
```

Since I'm no Windows user you have to make some small adaptions to this function, in order to be able to run it on Windows.

Note: there is also a `compilation-start-hook`, if you e.g. want to compare file-modification times of your exe.